# Need to pull list of users who have received impressions and clickthroughs for the campaign

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We need to pull the list of users who have received an impression of a particular campaign or an ad.

We need their click-through results as well for each use and for all campaigns and ads.

Right now the reporting API (i.e. /a/ads-reporting/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/campaigns/{campaignId}/segments/{segmentId}/users)  provides this, but with a caveat that the segment involved cannot exceed 150 users. but our user base is in 1000s and we need the entire list of users who received and acted on a campaign.

Answer (score 0):

For larger segments you will want to use the profile-export endpoints, which will provide exactly what you are looking for in terms of impressions and clickthrough.

See the [POST /a/ads-reporting/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/campaigns/{campaignId}/profile-exports](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/ads/reporting/#/profile-exports/post_a_ads_reporting_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__campaigns__campaignId__profile_exports) endpoints for details on how to initiate a new profile-export.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77462385/1239511 for additional information on the other profile-exports endpoints.